# How to map String to Seq<String> in Spark in Java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I want to use my own tokenizer to tokenize text stored as `Dataset<String>`, and get `Dataset<Seq<String>>` (so I can pass it to `CountVectorizer`).

Expected input (`/tmp/fulltext.txt`):

```
t1 t2 t3
t4 t5
```

Expected output:

```
[t1, t2, t3]
[t4, t5]
```

The tokenizer I write is (basically the thing it does now is the same as `Tokenizer` shipped with Spark, but I'll need to rewrite it to support tokenization of Chinese text, so I cannot use the official `Tokenizer`):

```
public class Utils {

  public static Seq<String> segment(String text) {
    String[] array = text.split(" ");
    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String term : array) {
      tokens.add(term.toLowerCase());
    }
    return JavaConverters
        .asScalaIteratorConverter(tokens.iterator())
        .asScala()
        .toSeq();
  }

}
```

The Spark application I'm trying to make is

```
public class TokenizeTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("Tokenize Test")
        .getOrCreate();

    Dataset<String> rawText = spark
        .read()
        .textFile("/tmp/fulltext.txt")
        .cache();

    Encoder<Seq> listEncoder = Encoders.bean(Seq.class);

    // Compilation error
    Dataset<Seq<String>> newText = rawText
        .map((MapFunction<String, Seq<String>>) s -> Utils.segment(s), listEncoder);

    newText.show();
    spark.stop();
  }
}
```

I'm a beginner of Spark, the above code is just what I think will work (after reading the official guide). But it turns out the code of `TokenizeTest` doesn't compile at all. Do you think there is a way to fix it?

Comment: `Seq` is not a bean. You will need a bean class with the `Encoder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Scala collections like this won't work. For once `Seq` is not Bean compatible, for second it is generic.

If you want split just use arrays with `segement` defined as:

```java
public class Utils {

  public static String[] segment(String text) {
    return text.split(" ");
  }

}
```

and `TokenizeTest` defined as:

```java
public class TokenizeTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("Tokenize Test")
        .getOrCreate();

    Dataset<String> rawText = spark
        .read()
        .textFile("/path/to/file")
        .cache();

    Encoder<String []> listEncoder = spark.implicits().newStringArrayEncoder();


    Dataset<String []> newText = rawText
        .map((MapFunction<String, String []>) s -> Utils.segment(s), listEncoder);

    newText.show();
    spark.stop();
  }
}
```

In practice though, you might consider either `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.split` or `org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer` instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: It works, thank you! Only that Intellij Idea can't recognize the `implicit()` method, which made me think the code wouldn't compile.